# Ambiguous occurrence '=='

Tags: haskell, instance, ambiguous

I'm just learning Haskell and still trying to figure out how things work.

So I'm creating a list class that can hold a mixture of `Int` and `Char`.

```
data Algebra = Empty
|   Nmbr Int Algebra
|   Smbl Char Algebra
```

Then I try to make it an instance of `Eq`

```
instance Eq Algebra where
Empty == Empty              = True
(Nmbr x xl) == (Nmbr y yl)  = (x == y) && (xl==yl)
(Smbl x xl) == (Smbl y yl)  = (x == y) && (xl==yl)
_ == _                  = False
```

and I get an  `Ambiguous occurrence ==` compile error. It can't tell the difference between `Main.==` and `Prelude.==`. If I manually replace all `==` with `Main.==` or `Prelude.==` then it compiles fine.

I don't see why the compiler is having so much difficulty here. `x` and `y` are clearly defined as being `Int` or `Char` in each case. I've compared what I am doing to the numerous tutorial examples (eg http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/classes.html) and I can't determine why the compiler is being such a jerk in this situation :P

Comment: Another Question: Does `deriving Eq` attempt to do exactly the same thing as my code here? I can't find a good explanation of how `deriving` works.

Comment: Yes, it does. See the [official language report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch11.html#x18-18300011.1).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to indent the body of your `instance` definition:

```
instance Eq Algebra where
  Empty == Empty              = True
  (Nmbr x xl) == (Nmbr y yl)  = (x == y) && (xl==yl)
  (Smbl x xl) == (Smbl y yl)  = (x == y) && (xl==yl)
  _ == _                  = False
```

Otherwise the compiler sees it as two things:

- An `instance Eq Algebra` with an empty body, producing the default definitions of `a == b = not (a /= b)` and vice versa.
- A definition of a new infix operator named `==`.

Then using `==` in your code now produces an ambiguity between the `==` from `Eq` (defined in `Prelude`) and the `==` in your code (`Main`).

And yes, `deriving Eq` gives you exactly this kind of structural equality.

Comment: Wow! I swear nobody ever explained that indents were a necessary part of Haskell coding. Thank you so much!

Comment: @StephenDouglasAllen: Indentation in Haskell is syntactic sugar for curly braces and semicolons. Check out the Haskell Report for the exact definition: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-210002.7

Comment: Another Question: Are the indents needed for the `data` statement? I'm assuming not because the `|` symbols hold it together, right?

Comment: @StephenDouglasAllen Yeah, they are needed. The `data` definition you gave doesn't compile for me. Also, by the way, I would suggest using spaces instead of tabs (just in case you're using tabs). It's definitely possible to effectively program in Haskell with tabs, but it can be less intuitive if you're not used to that style.

Comment: It's definitely *possible* to program in Haskell with tabs, but using tabs in Haskell code is like using all one-letter variable names in C: it's not *required* to win an obfuscated programming contest, but it certainly *helps*.